# Looking for amazing iPhone UI/UX designers

Tags: iphone

Can anyone recommend some amazing designers for iPhone user interfaces?

I'm looking to hire the 'best of the best' for a clients project. Apparently there is 'famous' designers for this - can't seem to find them though :(

Cheers

Comment: Famous, but can't find them? Does that even make sense?

Answer (score 2):

A 'best of the best' list will always be subjective. Find something that fits with what your client wants and find out who did it.

You're probably best off having a look through design showcases for iPhone apps like http://tapfancy.com/, finding interfaces you like, then find the designers who created them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [2010 winners of the Apple design awards](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/ada/ada2010winners.html). They were chosen based for a combination of excellence in design, innovation and technological excellence.